# What are some good roll tables for a DM screen?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques

I made myself a low-budget DM screen out of cardboard, but it doesn't have any tables or information. Does anybody know any essential tables for it? If so, can you share the link with me? I already printed out a weather table.

Comment: What are you looking for, conditions? modifiers? rules? Loot?

Comment: This sounds a bit opinion-based. After all it's impossible to say what is essential for you. I for example definitely need a name generator for NPC names, lights, status effects and travel distances. But someone else might be good at choosing names for example and instead need a short reference for when to use each skill.

Comment: If it helps, my game is only roughly planned out, with no exact dialogue or carefully planned out NPCs.

Comment: My advice would be to use the tables that you use the most.